# Pushing from TestFlight to AppStore new version

Tags: ios, mobile, app-store, app-store-connect, testflight

I'm uploaded my app to Testflight and it is working ok. Now I need to deploy  a new version in App Store. I readed the doc, but ITunesConnect has different user interface and I'm not sure how I can to push from ITunesConnect to AppStore in the simple way. Any idea, link?

Thanks.

Comment: Go through this, apple developer portal: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingTheApp.html

Comment: The documentation link provided by Imad does NOT have the answer. I am starting to think it is NOT POSSIBLE to simply click something to go from TestFlight to a real app submission. How completely absurd, there should be a simple way to do this.

Comment: @Gerry Agreed, why can't the release process be simple?

Answer (score 59):

For question regarding how to promote from Test Flight to App Store new version:

After expiring the Test Flight build as others explained, today the way it worked was:

1. Click blue + symbol to add iOS app

[image]

2. When you get the pop-up for `Store Version Number` - it **does not** need to match your actual build and version number.

[image]

3. Once you do this, you will then see the yellow *"Prepare for Submission"*

[image]

4. Click that and you will see the view to select the latest build

Comment: Wow! They made it hard to understand... This is the real answer!

Comment: Its 3 am in India. And i was looking for answer. Thanks man

Comment: Working at 3am is no joke. Glad this post was able to help a bit

Comment: I think it is not needed to expire the TestFlight version first. At least in early 2023 :)

Answer (score 24):

If you want to select a build from test flight and make it live on App-store follow these steps.

Note: there should be builds present in the test flight.

Go to https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/

Go to "My apps".

**Step 1**: Click on prepare for submission.

[image: Screenshot for step 1]

**Step 2**: Scroll down and go to builds section and click on "select your build".
[image: Screenshot for step 2]

**Step 3**: Select your build from the list of builds you have uploaded on test flight.

[image: Screenshot for step 3]

Comment: I'm not seeing my latest Testflight build on this screen - only an older one.

Comment: Okay - these instructions were fine. I just had to click on the "Prepare for submission" build, scroll down the page to 'Build', select the correct build, then scroll down even further to "General App Information", and type in a new version value, then save. The name that shows in the "Prepare for Submission" on the left is what's in that version box.

Comment: You need to go to "Screenshot for step 1" and in the left menu press "VERSION or PLATFORM". From drop down choose iOS and enter number for new version. Then scroll to the bottom and add build to version. (just choose from the list of files)

Answer (score 9):

Expire your build from testing and then create new release based on this build (blue button "+ VERSION OR PLATFORM" on left menu in "App Store" tab).
This is where you can submit version for review and then release automatically.

Comment: Now this... this is the real deal. Good answer. #Worked

Comment: Yeah don't do this. Expiring the build removes it from the App Store altogether (except from the Activity page) and you'll have to upload a new version. I learned the hard way.

Comment: I don't think you need to expire the build. Just add the version and you can find all related builds in the builds selection.

Comment: This made my app go for review a second time. There should be a way to promote beta to production without a re-review.

Answer (score 0):

Desmond:  From Apple Store Connect 
(https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devdc42b26b8)
From TestFlight directions:

Step 7: Stop testing
When you are done testing, you can optionally expire a build to stop testing it, and then go to Overview of publishing an app for the process of submitting your app to the App Store. If you don’t expire your build and submit it to the App Store, testers that have received an invite to test will still be able to test your build even after it goes live on the App Store. Your build will become unavailable in TestFlight after 90 days.